# How to track performance of a logistic regression model overtime?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I am in the process of deploying a logistic regression model. Specifically, a model used to predict churn. How would I track its performance overtime? Would I simply use a confusion matrix based? Or are there any more sophisticated/accurate ways of doing so?

Comment: It really depends on how you define "performance", i.e. precision, accuracy, etc? Which metrics are most important to you - for example is your sensitivity more important (for example accurately predicting those customers/subscribers who leave the service)?

Comment: In this case it would probably be a recall. Out of a large data set im concerned with the model detecting potential churn overall.

Comment: So why not call everything a potential churn so that you miss zero cases?

Comment: I don't know if thats genuine advice or you're just being a smart ***

Comment: In this case, you’re probably more interested in how well your model performs given new data. You first need to determine what your threshold for ‘good’ performance is. Then you need to decide over what time span you want to check the performance of the model. For example, acquire one week of ‘new data’ and then test the model with this data. Then repeat this for each subsequent week. Then plot the recall for the model as the y value and each incremental week as the x value. If you want to roughly estimate whether the model will fall below your threshold, you can then fit a regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As geedigit notes, it depends what is important to your application.  I doubt recall would be a good metric to monitor because it gets the conditioning incorrect.

In a probabalistic sense, recall is

$$ P(\hat{y} = 1 \vert y=1) \>. $$

In essence, of all the positive outcomes, what proportion did you predict were positive?  Note this quantity necessarily conditions on the outcome, hence it is best applied retrospectively.  Your application as I understand it is prospective, making recall inappropriate.

One approach may be to monitor some sort of proper scoring rule -- either the negative log likelihood or the Brier score -- and watch for degrading performance.  Because a proper scoring rule is maximized by the true probability distribution, any decrease in a proper scoring rule means your estimated probability distribution is moving farther from "the truth". Finally, you may want to monitor the "lift" in using the model month to month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.